# Request a certificate from the certificate authority

Tags: c#, certificate, certificate-authority

Phishing question.

I have a tcp server application that uses certificates for tls/ssl and stored in the pkcs#12 file.  Assuming a CA is installed somewhere on the network and is accessible,  would it be normal practice to request a ssl certificate from the CA (once), programmatically (C#) and write it out to the pkcs#12 file for use by the server.

Would that be normal practice, or would the more likely scenario be a case of buying the certificate from a CA like Thawte or Versign etc, specically for that customer, and creating the pkcs#12 file beforehand, and installing as part of installation process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a case where the argument can go either way.

Programmatic certificate requests and signing have their merits if you need to manage a large number of sites, at the loss of human-mediated validation if something goes horribly wrong (for example, if someone hijacks or listens in on your initial request). At some point, a trust decision needs to be made, either programmatically, or as a human operator.

[This paper by Bruce Schneier](http://www.schneier.com/paper-pki-ft.txt) goes into more detail, discussing potential risks to the CA architecture underpinning the trust decisions for [PKI cryptography](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure). I believe this covers many cases that are pertinent to your issue and your design that you may not have, and should, consider.

Comment: MrGomez, thanks for the link, but I think I read that paper ages ago. An excellent paper, but i'm really looking for practical, cogent, current advice.

Comment: @scope_creep Fair enough. Leaving out all of the platitudes associated with managing trust networks and establishing the trust chain all the way to the root of your PKI, [this article and its associated links](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alejacma/archive/2011/11/07/how-to-request-a-certificate-programmatically-using-the-certificate-enrollment-web-services-c.aspx) may offer guidance. Pathing down its link tree a bit, I noticed that the author's advice was to log a Technical Support case with Microsoft. That may be worth doing, just to get specific advice targeted to your problem. Good luck!